# How to find if a number in a row matches a number in a column, and then automatically offset the number in the column to another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to find if a number in a row matches a number in a column, and then automatically offset the number in the column to another value. For example:

```
Row    0 1 2 3 4 5 
Answer x x x x x x

Column 
0       100
1       340
2       500
3       266
4       455
5       800
```

So if "0" in the Row array matches "0" in the Column array, then show 340 and so on. I can to this with nested IF statements but is there an easier way if you have 100s of columns. Thanks

Comment: Vlookup, Xlookup, Index/Match will all do what you ask.